# Browser's loading AngularJS variables as URLs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest

We've been getting a strange error recently on a high volume website,

Ultimately this is the error that is being logged to our system

```
Uncaught Exception: The page you requested, assets/en-GB/assets/scripts/'+$scope.iframeURL+', could not be found. in file system/core/Framework.php on line 789
```

For some reason, there does not seem to be a pattern, the users browser is requesting the `$scope.iframeURL` variable as a script file?

Additionally, it also requests the file from the scripts folder rather than the `base href` which causes the double `/assets/en-GB/assets`

any thoughts as to why this could be happening?

Comment: It seems like you are using `$scope.iframeURL` as a string rather than a variable. Check the use of single quotes `'` before and after $scope.iframeURL.

Please share the exact code which makes the request so as to determine base href.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to answer your question without seeing your html/javascript.

Maybe you're setting a src attribute directly instead of using [`ngSrc`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)? This would cause that the browser already requests some resource before Angular has been initialized, so the browser is loading an incorrect url until Angular has finished initializing.

Comment: I must admit its not my code so I dont know exactly what/where it is, but from the look of the variable name being "iframeURL" would suggest there could be an iframe src="{{iframeURL}}" lurking about! I'll give this a look thanks!

Comment: I've found this piece of javascript -> `content.after('<iframe src="'+$scope.iframeURL+'" class="inline-video"></iframe>');` so its not being rendered by HTML, so could the browser/bot be reading that line of code from the JS files and trying to pass it?

Comment: @OwenMelbourne Google parses and executes javascript (see [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.be/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html)), so other bots might as well. You could try to add some more logging from where this request is coming from.